# calling API before loading angular project using APP_INITIALIZER

Tags: angular, typescript

In my project, I want to make an http request then load the angular app. After doing some research I found that using APP_INITIALIZER do this. After looking at some tutorials, my code is still not working. When I print the data that is fetched from the API, I see in the console window `ZoneAwarePromise`. I don't know why I can't see the data in the console window. Btw, is APP_INITIALIZER the good way to do this?

The files are the following (Please let me know if something is not clear):

**app.module.ts**

```
export function basicLoader(provider: ElevationService){
  return()=>{
    console.log('Basic Loader');
    return provider.getInfo();
  };
}

@NgModule({ declarations: [AppComponent,RackbaseComponent,OoComponent,ItemComponent, SlotsComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    // MatNativeDateModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  providers: [ElevationService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: basicLoader, deps:[ElevationService], multi: true,
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

**elevation.service.ts**

```
  public getInfo(){

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.get(this.j1Elevation).subscribe(res => {
      resolve(true);
    })})
  }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {


  allData: any = [];

  constructor(private elevation: ElevationService){
    console.log("inside app component");
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.allData = this.elevation.getInfo();
    // printing the data here shows 'ZonAwarePromise'
    console.log(this.allData);
  }

  dontShow(){
    this.isShown = false;
  }


}
```

Comment: You've changed `getInfo()` to return a promise, not to return data. - You don't set the data anywhere anyhow. APP_INITIALIZER is an ok approach, but a `resolver` might be easier to reason about